# Can't delete records, duplicated when creating

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding

I have 2 tables in my MySQL DB where column "campaignid" in table "pages" refference (= to) column "id" in the table "campaigns.

```
ALTER TABLE pages ADD FOREIGN KEY (campaignid) REFERENCES campaigns(id);
```

The data in these columns is called by this public function:

```
public function get_pages_by_campaign_id($campaignID) {
    $campaignID = $this->real_escape_string($campaignID);
    return $this->query("SELECT pid, campaignid FROM pages campaigns WHERE campaignid = 'campaigns.id'");
}
```

However when I try to delete a "page" using:

```
 public function delete_page($pageID) {
    $this->query("DELETE FROM pages WHERE id = " . $pageID);
}
```

Nothing happens. Should I have set something like `ON DELETE SET NULL | ON UPDATE CASCADE` or something????

At the moment I cannot update, delete or save anything to the DB, which has been the case for 2 days now ... any help would be Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: You should start by checking your if your queries return errors, the errors will probably tell you what you need to do.

Comment: I have checked with this :  
`printf("User ID: %d ", $userID);
      printf("Page ID: %d ", $pageID);
      printf("Campaign ID: %d ", $campaignsID);
      printf("Result: %s ", print_r($page, true));
      printf("Result: %s ", print_r($campaigns, true));
      $db = PageDB::getInstance();
      printf("Error: %s (%d)" . PHP_EOL, $db->error, $db->errno);`

and there's no errors ...

Comment: I found an error : `Error: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (1054)` But canot find the source "id"

Comment: Can you print out the SQL that your code is generating, and paste it into the database to see if the queries themselves work?

Comment: There you go; SELECT is looking for pid, and DELETE is looking for id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Your query uses `campaignid = 'campaigns.id'` but the quotes indicate that is a variable, when I assume its the column you're looking for. You need commas between the table names. You also don't use the variable you pass into the function.

```
public function get_pages_by_campaign_id($campaignID) {
    $campaignID = $this->real_escape_string($campaignID);
    return $this->query("SELECT pid, campaignid FROM pages, campaigns WHERE campaignid= campaigns.id AND campaignid = '$campaignID' ");
}
```

I assume you want to get data from the campaigns table in your query too? Otherwise you don't need to include it in the query.

EDIT: AS stated in the comments you use id in your delete - should that be pid like you use in the select? Also, put quotes around the variable (not necessary but prevents DB error is the variable is empty)

```
$this->query("DELETE FROM pages WHERE pid = '" . $pageID. "'");
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found that "id" - sorry been up all night working on this, can't see the forest for the trees and all that !

Comment: This has returned an erro:
`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (1064)`

Comment: @user1395580 It wasn't just the one id - I made 3 or 4 changes to your select query too so make sure you get those too! Edit: just saw your comment - is this for the select or delete? I had to guess your database structure so are the columns etc correct?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - I found the elusive "id"'s
The colums are deffinitely correct ...
I change the function with this query:
`"SELECT pid , campaignid FROM pages , campaigns WHERE campaignid = campaigns.id"` and it now seems to work.

Comment: It looks like its a problem with $campaignID - does it have a value when its passed into the function? The error said to check the syntax near '' so that suggests the query is getting empty quotes

Comment: Here's the full result : `User ID: 1 Page ID: 260 Campaign ID: 0 Error: (0)` Even though there's no error now, it is not referencing the Campaigns.ID

Comment: can you print the actual query thats being passed to the database? if your $campaignID variable is not set them that could be the problem, otherwise its not the query so it must be the foreign key is incorrect

Comment: This is what is calling the data for campaigns :
`if ($_POST['campaignsID'] == "") {
        PageDB::getInstance()->create_campaign($userid,
  $_POST['campaign_name'],
  $_POST['date_created']);
        header('Location: editPage.php');
        exit; 
      
    } else if ($_POST['campaignsID'] != "") {
        PageDB::getInstance()->update_campaign($userid,$campaignID,
  $_POST['campaign_name'] );
        header('Location: editPage.php');
  exit;
    }

}`

Comment: @user1395580 thatcode doesn't show where the function get_pages_by_campaign_id is being called, which is the one with the error. However I meant thatyou need to print out the query itself to see what is being passed to the database. e.g. `$SQL = "SELECT pid, campaignid FROM pages, campaigns WHERE campaignid= campaigns.id AND campaignid = '$campaignID' "; echo $SQL; return $this->query($SQL);`